# py2exe, windows 10: [WinError87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, windows-10, py2exe

I have a python project which I build with py2exe. Under Windows 7 it works without problems. If I build the same project, with the same virtual environment and the same python version under windows 10, I get the error "[WinError87] The parameter is incorrect".

The error occurs in the runtime.py of py2exe in line 335:

```
328: # It seems resources must be updated in chunks if there are
329: # many, otherwise EndUpdateResource will fail with
330: # WindowsError 13 (invalid data)
331: with UpdateResources(exe_path, delete_existing=True) as resource:
332:     if self.options.verbose > 1:
333:         print("Add resource %s/%s(%d bytes) to %s"
334:               % ("PYTHONSCRIPT", 1, len(script_info), exe_path))
335:     resource.add(type="PYTHONSCRIPT", name=1, value=script_info)
```

I use python 3.4.4 32 Bit with py2exe 0.9.2.2.

Can someone help me please?